# Creating a Web Service in JavaEE

Tags: java, web-services

I'm new to creating web services in Java, thus the question.

I have an object,

```
public class Course {

    private int _id;
    private String _name;
    private Person _person;
}
```

I have data about the object stored in a file, which I've already parsed and stored in a local array list.

My DataService object does this.

```
public DataService(){

        _personList = new ArrayList<>();
        _courseList = new ArrayList<>();

        //logic to parse data and read into a QueryHandler object.

        _handler = new QueryHandler(_personList, _courseList);

    }
```

Now this data service has a GET method which displays the list of all courses.

```
   @GET
    @Produces("application/JSON")
    public ArrayList<Course> getAllCourses(){
        return _handler.getAllCourses();

    }
```

My question is how do I expose this method as an endpoint, so that the caller can get a link like `example.com/getAllCourses` or something like `example.com/getCourseById/21`(method already created) which will return the data in JSON format ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add `@Path("/course")` to your class and change your method to

```
@GET
@Path("/getAllCourses")
@Produces("application/JSON")
public ArrayList<Course> getAllCourses(){
    return _handler.getAllCourses();

}
```

And if you want to get a specific id you'll write

```
@GET
@Path("getCourseById/{id}")
@Produces("application/JSON")
@Consumes("application/JSON")
public Course getCourseById(@PathParam("id") int id){
    return _handler.getCourseById(id);

}
```

The path will be `host.com/course/getAllCourses` or `host.com/course/getCourseByid/1` for example

Here is a doc' about it [JAX-RS](http://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-rs/jax-rs-pathparam-example/)

Comment: Just one doubt, my application is using GlassFish as a server, how do I access these API's on a browser.

Comment: Are you using maven?

Comment: Nope I'm using the Gradle build system.

Comment: (Late answer) You have to type the URL ;)